# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error on windows

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm building a simple program to go through a list of URLs and extract their content using beautiful soup. For the minute I'm just trying to iterate through the list and retrieve the html but I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/thoma/PycharmProjects/fyp/urls_and_prep/parsing_html.py", line 17, in <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

My program is simple enough but I can't understand or find any good resources for working out what exactly is going on/ how to handle it. I know its something to do with SSL certificates but I'm not sure where how to use them or where to install them etc. I'm just at a bit of a loss with this one as I've never really worked with SSL before. Any guidance or help is greatly appreciated. Here's the code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = open("all_urls.txt", "r")

for line in file:
    print(line)

    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(line)
        html = response.read()
    except ValueError:
        print(ValueError)
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: There are [many questions about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+python+certificate+failed). If these don't help and you want to get help with your specific question please provide enough detail to reproduce the problem. This means especially the URL where your code fails.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows or Linux? This problem seems to be not on Python, but in Anaconda or in the OS. You can try some simple solutions, like: 1 - Execute the scrypt using other Python installation than the one from Anaconda. 2 - Use the virtualenv to isolate the components of the OS.

Comment: I'm using windows with anaconda but i think i had python and a few libraries installed before i installed anaconda. Would reinstalling python/anaconda help do you think? Thanks for the reply?

Comment: The installation of single Python and the Python from Anaconda are in different places. Try to pass the full path of the Python when you execute the script. Ex: `C:\Program Files\Python34\Python xxxxxxxx.py`

Answer (score 0):

Below will fix the problem. But be sure not to use in production as it will be working without verifying the SSL certificate-

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# This is a temporary fix .Be carefule of malicious links
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
file = open("all_urls.txt", "r")

for line in file:
    print(line)

    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(line, context=context)
        html = response.read()
    except ValueError:
        print(ValueError)
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: Ok that's great for now, i know that none of the links on my list are malicious so that should work. I'll be using this code on a crawler later though, so what would you recommend in that scenario where i don't know what links I'll be checking? Thanks so much for the reply, really appreciated.